# ios: How to implement navigation of a slide out menu?

Tags: ios, navigation

So far I have been working with NavigationController. It's great for hierarchical navigation.

But, how do I implement a slide out menu that exists on every page, and is able to jump to any page?
Not caring about the design, I guess we would need to load/unload xib files manually to the superview?

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to get you going is to implement/check some of the already developed open source solutions.

Please, check out:
[MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) which is a simpler version
and [MSDynamicsDrawerViewController](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController) which is a bit more complicated (to develop) because it uses iOS 7 Dynamics.

Cheers.